# Is it worth using tip activator to replace the protective coating on the iron tip (or should I replace the tip)?

Tags: soldering

I have a 48W ZD99 Solder Station. The protective coating on the iron's tip is starting to peel/break off. I believe this is due to a combination of moisture in the air where I live and incorrect care for the iron on my part. (I started using it before I knew that applying flux and tinning it would keep it in working order.) The current state of the iron's tip can be seen in the image below:

[image: Coating coming off iron tip]

The slightly lighter area is where there is still coating. If you look carefully, you can see the ragged line between the coated and uncoated areas.

I have read [soldering tip issues](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/solder-iron-tip-issues) and the answers thereto, which suggest that it's possible to get something called "tip activator" for recoating tips and that it works reliably well. Assuming that I can't buy any from the stores I usually go to, what's my next best option.

Comment: clean it with a wire brush then use flux / solder and keep it working : I have old soldering irons with old tips with no protective coating or fancy "tip activator" (which sounds like a snake oil ...) which still work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'll give that a try and see if that helps.

Comment: And perhaps a gentle shape up with a file... depends if it is a cpper tip with a coating though...

Comment: That looks way past the stage fixable with those activators (which are just a suspension of tiny solder droplets in a fairly aggressive flux). I'd use a [brass sponge](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/2/2/6/9/08965-03-L.jpg) to clean the oxidation, followed immediately by the generous application of flux-core solder wire to the whole tip. Using steel wool, steel scrubbing pads, a metal file or sandpaper certainly cleans the tip, but also destroys the coating.

Comment: I think it's an iron tip. (It was a bit rusty, rather than tarnished.) Going at it with a brush and flux sorted it out. I've managed to tin it now. Thanks for your advice. I thought it was a goner.

Comment: Don't you mean a copper tip with an iron coating? That is what is commonly used. It's best to replace the tip when the iron coating is damaged.

Comment: @SolarMike: If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest cleaning it with a wire brush then use flux / solder and keep it working.

I have old soldering irons with old tips with no protective coating or fancy "tip activator" (which sounds like a snake oil ...) which still work fine.